# JS how to deep copy two objects

Tags: javascript

I have an obj1:

```
const obj1 = { val: {v: 0}}
```

I'm trying to deep copy it by doing:

```
const obj2 = {...obj1}
```

However the `{v: 0}` is still not copied, how would I do this>

Comment: As long as there are no things like functions or instances of classes in your object, you could do a ' dirty' JSON conversion. So; `const obj2 = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj1 ) );`.

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me.

Comment: @Phix nope :  `obj1.val.v = 1` also change the value of `obj2.val.v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the easiest way, but a bit clumsy

```js
const obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))
```

Otherwise you need to write a recursive cloning function or use some library - just search for cloneDeep, copyDeep or smth along these lines.

Comment: This is really just the old school way (with far more risk) of doing `const obj2 = { ...obj1 }` Doing `JSON.stringify` will modify your object in a lot of ways that you may not want it to (ie loss of functions, data type conversions etc...)

Comment: @mwilson, `const obj2 = { ...obj1 }` doesn't do deep copy, only shallow (top level props). Yes, you're right on functions etc, but in many cases you just need to clone POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash-es` package for this. It provides the function `cloneDeep()` that will recursively clone values.

Here is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es

Here are the Docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

```
import { cloneDeep as _cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es';

const obj2  = _cloneDeep(obj1);
```

Comment: Bring in an entire library just to clone one object?

Comment: No, when using `lodash-es` only what you import will be included in final bundle. If you import just `cloneDeep`, only that one will be included in final bunde, and not the whole package.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it how you should (with the spread operator). The spread operator will copy everything just fine.

```js
const obj1 = { val: {v: 0} };
const obj2 = { ...obj1 };
console.log(obj2);
```

```js
const obj1 = {
  test: 1,
  test2: {
    t: 1,
    f: () => console.log('hello')
  }
};
const obj2 = { ...obj1 };
console.log( obj2 );
console.log( obj2.test2.f() );
```

If you were to (at any time) do a `JSON.stringify` on the object, you will lost any methods/functions or other things that don't translate to the json scheme so it's best to avoid doing that. [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is what you want.

Comment: bad copy because `obj1.val.v = 1`  also change the value of `obj2.val.v`

Comment: Yes, that's a good point to higlight on. OP didn't mention anything about setting values, but yes, in the case you mentioned, it will require deep destructuring.

Comment: no, the OP mention **deep copy**

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough rep to even flag but this is a cleeeeeear duplicate of a lot of questions

even googling the title would have been easier for you

anyway I use a module called rfdc that does just that, and lodash has a function to do it to
otherwise you can loop through your src object with a recursive function that adds fields to your dest object